# What is the significance of being resurrected as "blind (from birth)"?

Tags: tafseer, arabic, surat-ta-ha

In Surah Taha, Allah says:

[image]

> He will say, "My Lord, why have you raised me blind while I was [once]
>   seeing?" ([Surah Taha, verse 125](http://quran.com/20/125))

From surah 'abasa, we know that the word used here and translated as blind, أَعْمَىٰ (a3maa) means *blind from birth*. It does not refer to a person who acquired blindness during their lifetime after having the ability to see.

This seems interesting -- that a person who, by their own admission, *could see in their dunya life,* is now *resurrected blind (from birth).* What is the significance of the word a'maa here, as opposed to a different word that could have been used to describe "could once see but is now blind"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In tafseer, scholars commented that this means the person will have no proof to justify his deeds in dunya (world). There will be no evidence supporting him.

Mujahid, Abu Salih and As-Suddi said,

> "This means he will have no proof."

`Ikrimah said,

> "He will be made blind to everything except Hell."

It is because of what Allah the Exalted says in Surah Al-Isra :

> And We shall gather them together on the Day of Resurrection on their
>   faces, blind, dumb and deaf; their abode will be Hell. [**[Qur'an
>   17:97](http://quran.com/17/97)**]

**Source:** [Tafseer Ibn Katheer](http://www.qtafsir.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=896&Itemid=74)

Answer (score 2):

By blind God does not mean physical eye. It is about eye of heart and it means seeing truth but not accepting it and having dogma about some false beliefs. Anything in other life is reflect of our behaviors in this life.

> [[7:198]](http://tanzil.net/#7:198)  And if you invite them to guidance, they do not hear;
>   and you see them looking at you while they do not see.
>
> [[7:179]](http://tanzil.net/#7:179)  And We have certainly created for Hell many of the
>   jinn and mankind. They have hearts with which they do not understand,
>   they have eyes with which they do not see, and they have ears with
>   which they do not hear. Those are like livestock; rather, they are
>   more astray. It is they who are the heedless.
>
> [[10:43]](http://tanzil.net/#10:43)  And among them are those who look at you. But can you
>   guide the blind although they will not [attempt to] see?
>
> [[36:9]](http://tanzil.net/#36:9)  And We have put before them a barrier and behind them a
>   barrier and covered them, so they do not see.
>
> [[2:7]](http://tanzil.net/#2:7)  Allah has set a seal upon their hearts and upon their
>   hearing, and over their vision is a veil. And for them is a great
>   punishment.
>
> [[16:108]](http://tanzil.net/#16:108)  Those are the ones over whose hearts and hearing and
>   vision Allah has sealed, and it is those who are the heedless.

Comment: As mentioned in Surah Abasa, "idhaa jaa'ahu al-a3maa" means the one who was blind (Abdullah ibn Umm Maktoom). It does refer to physical blindness, linguistically and historically in tafseer.

Comment: @ashes999 yes this verse is physical blind. but this not mean all blind in Quran are physical. some are physical and some for heart (not accepting truth). above verses are clear.